# What part of speech is the word "running" in "I kept running"?

Tags: verbs, gerunds, parts-of-speech

What part of speech is the word "running" in "I kept running"?

I think it's a noun (gerund) but I'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "running" is a gerund-participial or "-ing" form of the verb "run". It is part of a catenative construction with "kept".

See:
[Wiktionary English catenative verbs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs)

> **keep**
> *I didn't get anything, so I **kept trying** my best.*

See also:
[Wikpedia catenative verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb)